# File Encryption Decryption with AES

Tags: java, encryption, aes

```java
public long copyStreamsLong(InputStream in, OutputStream out, long sizeLimit) throws IOException {

        long byteCount = 0;
        IOException error = null;
        long totalBytesRead = 0;
        try {
            String key = "C4F9EA21977047D6"; // user value (16/24/32 bytes)
            // byte[] keyBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(aesKey);
            SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
            System.out.println(secretKey.toString());
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[CustomLimitedStreamCopier.BYTE_BUFFER_SIZE];
            // in.read(buffer);
            int bytesRead = -1;
            while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                // We are able to abort the copy immediately upon limit violation.
                totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
                if (sizeLimit > 0 && totalBytesRead > sizeLimit) {
                    StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();
                    msg.append("Content size violation, limit = ").append(sizeLimit);
                    throw new ContentLimitViolationException(msg.toString());
                }
                byte[] obuf = cipher.update(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                if (obuf != null) {
                    out.write(obuf);
                }
                    byteCount += bytesRead;
            }
            byte[] obuf = cipher.doFinal();
            if (obuf != null) {
                out.write(obuf);
            }
                    out.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                error = e;
                CustomLimitedStreamCopier.logger.error("Failed to close input stream: " + this, e);
            }
            try {
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                error = e;
                CustomLimitedStreamCopier.logger.error("Failed to close output stream: " + this, e);
            }
        }
        if (error != null)
            throw error;
        return byteCount;
    }
     public InputStream getContentInputStream() throws ContentIOException {
        ReadableByteChannel channel = getReadableChannel();
        InputStream is = Channels.newInputStream(channel);
        try {    
            final String ALGORITHM = "AES";
            final String TRANSFORMATION = "AES";
            String key = "C4F9EA21977047D6";
            Key secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), ALGORITHM);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION);
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            byte[] buffer = ByteStreams.toByteArray(is);
            System.out.println("in read" + buffer.length);
            is.read(buffer);
            byte[] outputBytes = cipher.doFinal(buffer);            
            is = new ByteArrayInputStream(outputBytes);
}
```

When i m trying to encrypt input stream i will get increased byte array and after that when i will decrypt that input stream at that time in decryption it will take original byte size .so,when i tried to open that file it will give error that premature end tag so i want same file size after encryption ,and this method is part of java class.

What will be the solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialize the cipher with the TRANSFORMATION = "**AES**" and that means that your Java implementation will choose a default AES mode, usually it is "**AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding**". Beneath the fact that **ECB-mode is unsecure and should not any longer used** for plaintext/streams longer than 16 bytes the padding will add additional bytes up to a (multiple) blocklength of 16.

So running my small program you see that in your implementation an inputLen of "10" (means a plaintext/stream of 10 byte length) will result in an outputSize of "16".

To avoid this you do need another AES mode and that the output is of the same length as the input on encryption side. You can use **AES CTR mode** for this - you just need an additional parameter (initialization vector, 16 byte long). It is very important that you **never ever use the same iv for more than 1 encryption** so it should get generated as random value. For decryption the recipient of the message ("the decryptor") needs to know what initvector was used on encryption side.

```
cipher algorithm: AES                  inputLen  10 outputSize  16
cipher algorithm: AES/CTR/NOPADDING    inputLen  10 outputSize  10
```

**Edit (security warning):** As reminded by President James K. Polk "*CTR mode makes it trivial to modify individual bytes of the attacker's choosing, so it needs to be coupled with an authentication tag.*". It depends on the kind of data that are going to get encrypted if they need a authentication (e.g. if you are encrypting music files then any modifying will result in a "piep" or "krk", changing of financial data will end catastrophical).

code:

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.security.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
        System.out.println("");
        int inputLen = 10;
        final String ALGORITHM = "AES";

        // aes ecb mode
        final String TRANSFORMATION = "AES";
        //final String TRANSFORMATION = "AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING";
        String key = "C4F9EA21977047D6";
        Key secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), ALGORITHM);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        System.out.format("cipher algorithm: %-20s inputLen %3d outputSize %3d%n", cipher.getAlgorithm(), inputLen, cipher.getOutputSize(inputLen));

        // aes ctr mode
        String TRANSFORMATION2 = "AES/CTR/NOPADDING";
        // you need an unique (random) iv for each encryption
        SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
        byte[] iv = new byte[16];
        secureRandom.nextBytes(iv);
        IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        Cipher cipher2 = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION2);
        cipher2.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivParameterSpec);
        System.out.format("cipher algorithm: %-20s inputLen %3d outputSize %3d%n", cipher2.getAlgorithm(), inputLen, cipher2.getOutputSize(inputLen));
    }
}
```

A running implementation of the AES CTR-mode can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62662276/8166854

Comment: CTR mode makes it trivial to modify individual bytes of the attacker's choosing, so it needs to be coupled with an authentication tag. Which is basically what GCM provides.

Comment: @President James K. Polk: thanks for raising your hand and point to the part that makes CTR used "stand alone" unsecure. CTR-mode is - as far as I know - the only AES mode that produces the same length for plain data and encrypted data. GCM-mode adds some bytes for the tag. The AES-mode that is actually in use is ECB mode which is bad as well :-) Any other ideas that can help in this case?

Comment: It would seem from a purely information-theoretic perspective you cannot obtain authenticated encryption without making the ciphertext longer than the plaintext. If you must have the same length then you have to live without authentication. I believe the best mode in this case is [XTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_encryption_theory#XTS). It is still an unauthenticated mode **but** changing a single bit of ciphertext will have a bigger effect on the decrypted result and is not as controllable.

Comment: @President James K. Polk - XTS seems to be "heavy gun" but you're right, I edited my answer and added a security warning - thanks. Do you have a link to a working XTS example?

Comment: Good edit. I don't have any XTS examples and Java doesn't have any direct support for XTS, you'd have to build it yourself from ECB mode.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that it worked for you. Could you kindly mark the answer as accepted please?

Comment: @Michael i want to add something that ,if i want to check that file input stream is encrypted or not so how can i check this at decryption time because i want differentiation between simple files and encrypted file at decryption time .

Comment: As you didn't wrote anything above the filetype it's difficult to answer. One answer could be ("If working with a ZIP-file you could check the first 2 bytes to be 'PK' - that is the beginning of a ZIP-file"). All other answers would go far beyond the original question and are more a "software design" than crypto question.

Comment: @Michael thanks to quick reply, actually i have method in decryption as i mentioned in the code ,in that method i will get all types of files but i have to applied decryption on stream of that file ,as we discussed i used  CTR mode of encryption.